# Difference between devices manager drivers and

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just installed a new french keyboard driver from [here](http://users.numericable.be/denis.liegeois/kbdfrac.htm) on my W7, in order to be able to type more french characters. It comes as an executable so I cannot know what it really does. Once installed, it works fine and appears well in *Control Panel > Language and Region > Keyboards and languages tab >Modify the keyboards ...*

[image: keyboard layout]

But what I don't understand is that it seems to have no effect whatsoever on the *Devices Manager* data: the Keyboard section still remains with the usual two *HID keyboard device* entries, I don't even know why there are two of them in the first place (I only have one keyboard afaik).

[image: device manager]

So my purely academic question is: what is the **difference** and the **relation** between what is called a keyboard driver in the *Keyboards and languages* control panel (its name is "Français [...]" and seems to be basically only a layout), and what is called a keyboard driver in the *Devices Manager* and whose linked files are `system32\DRIVERS\kbdclass.sys` and `kndhid.sys`.

Comment: Where does the Keyboards and Languages Control Panel say "drivers"? That Control Panel item only manages input languages (software). Your keyboard drivers (kbdclass.sys and kbdhid.sys) are language-independent. They only serve to tell your computer how to communicate with your keyboard and vice-versa.

Comment: Well on the download website the developer himself says it's a keyboard driver. Is he wrong? And how can the keyboard drivers be language-independent?